# Divide a long string with a long integer

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to divide a long string containing only digits with a long integer. So i try to do it something like this :

```
string divide(string s,long long num)
{
bool flag=true; 
while(flag)
{
    string result="";
    flag=false;
    long long int length=s.size();
    long long int d=0,j=-1;
    for(long long int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        d*=10;
        d+=s[i]-48;
        if(j==-1 && d/num!=0)
            j=i;
        result+=(char)(d/num + 48);
        d%=num;
    }

    if(d==0)
    {
        s="";
        for(long long int i=j;i<length;i++)
            s+=result[i];
        factors.push_back(num);
        flag=true;
    }
 }
 return s;
}
```

But I think it get slow for big strings.So is their any faster way to divide a string with long integer .

Also please help me how to implement modulo operation for the same in a better way.

Comment: @djechlin Runtime of my code ?

Comment: you said it gets slow. what does that mean?

Comment: @djechlin For string of 1000 length it takes a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

```
for(long long int i=0;i<length;i++)
{
    d*=10;
    d+=s[i]-48;
    if(j==-1 && d/num!=0)
        j=i;
    result+=(char)(d/num + 48);
    d%=num;
}
```

You're computing `d/num` twice here, which is wasteful, but I would forget about remembering the `j` value inside this loop completely and just maximize it for speed. You should also accumulate `result` as an array rather than a string, and not use `long long` for array indices or loop counters:

```
char result[1000]; // or whatever your upper limit is
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    d = d*10+s[i]-'0';
    result[i] = (char)(d/num + '0');
    d %= num;
}
```

and then skip the leading zeros when you're finished. Depending on how your input is generated, it may also be worthwhile skipping leading zeros in the dividend before you start the loop.

NB your code doesn't work correctly if `d != 0` at the end. It returns the dividend rather than the quotient, if there was a remainder. This is probably OK if you are factorizing but it's a trap for young players copying this.

Comment: Why? I've given you the guts of it. The rest is just skipping leading zeros and forming the result string. Nothing to it. Your own code isn't a complete function either: it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use unsigned long long here, eliminating the unecessary clutter of the sign bit.

If your unsigned long long can manage numbers up to 10^n, then the division will not work if your divisor is > 10^(n-1).  But that may not be an issue for you.

Assuming 64-bit unsigned long long, we can handle up to 10^19.  There is no need to do any dividing until you have read 19 digits (after any leading zeros), and then you can proceed, collecting a number of digits of the result for each division -- where that number depends on the size of the divisor.

So, supposing we have a divisor, 10^11 < divisor <= 10^12, and we can handle up to 10^19, then:

1. read 19 digits (skipping leading zeros), then divide: which will
   generate the first 8 or 9 digits of the result and the initial
   remainder.

   This first step is similar to steps 3 and 4 except: (a) there is, obviously, no need to add leading zeros to the result, and (b) the first division may produce 9 digits of the result, where subsequent divisions are guaranteed to produce 8.  (Because on subsequent divisions we are dealing with the remainder to date, which is bound to be < divisor * 10^8.)
2. read a further 8 digits of the dividend (multiplying remainder by 10^8 and adding in those digits).
3. while the remainder is less than 10^18, read further digits of the dividend -- adding a zero for each further digit to the result.
4. divide to generate the next 8 digits of the answer and update remainder.
5. go back to step 2.
6. obviously, when you run out of digits you need to do a final division, giving the last digits of the result (between 1 and 7 digits, depending).  But that's an SMOP.

Note: given how slow `%` is, you could replace it by a multiply and subtract -- though your compiler may do that for you.  (Sadly, I cannot find a `ulldiv()` in the standard.)

If your divisor is small (for an unsigned long long), this will generate many digits of the result at a time.  If it is large, then perhaps only one or two.  I don't know if it is worth collecting two unsigned long long's worth of dividend and doing a double word division... but if the input number is very, very long, then collecting 18 or more digits of the answer at a time looks tempting to me !